# How to install Semantic UI into Dreamweaver?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, semantic-ui

Sorry if this sounds dumb, but I'm brand new to Javascript libraries/repos. All I basically need to do is be able to use the Dropdown functionality in Semantic UI: https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

I have the zip file installed and it comes with different CSS/JS files, but how exactly do I incorporate this into my code? Do I just copy the javascript content into my code?

Any help/guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/advanced-usage.html

Looks like you can include the CDN scripts into your html file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that- I've already seen this, but for some reason it still doesn't work. All it does is change the fonts/margins a bit, but there is no searchable functionality in the dropdown menu. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/femnw7ow/1/       What's not working? Thanks again!

Comment: You will need to structure the HTML of your drop down menu as they do in the documentation for the drop down module on their site. After including the semantic ui script and css you need to initialize your drop down with something like `$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown()`. See https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/usage. Also here is a working fiddle of a drop down https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/usage

Comment: Did you make a fiddle? Can't see it- maybe seeing a working example would help. That makes more sense- I guess this is getting complicated because I also have another Javascript function that is creating the options in the menu (selectStock), which may be interfering with this UI- I tried simply incorporating what it said by putting the dropdown code in Javascript, but now it's just totally taking away the functionality of my dropdown

Comment: My code isn't set up in a div at all- I have to use the data from the dropdown  to calculate other code, and the dropdown items are all taken from an array. How can I then incorporate this?

Comment: You'll just have to update your JS code to create divs rather than select options. You'll need to match what semantic UI is expecting.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm not sure how to just make it as a list. This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/femnw7ow/3/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/femnw7ow/4/

I updated the function that renders the list items to render div's. jQuery needs to be loaded before the semantic UI

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work, but for some reason it's not linking/outputting the functions. Also the formatting is a bit off. I'm trying to link the data from the dropdown menu to make the calculations, but I don't know how to do that using the divs that are required here. Thoughts?